# Projecting 3D points into 2D

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, projection

I'm trying to convert 3D points using camera pose (position and orientation). 
Camera Position is at ( 0, 1400, 0) 
The problem is the projected 2D points are not normalized to (-1,1) where 0,0 is the center of the screen (image)

here is my equations

```
  std::vector<Ogre::Vector2> projectedFeaturePoints;
        Core::CameraIntrinsics cameraIntrinsics = Core::EnvironmentInformation::getSingleton()->getCameraIntrinsics();
        for (int i = 0; i < out.numberofpoints; i++)
        {
            Ogre::Vector4 pt;
            pt.x = out.pointlist[i];
            pt.y = out.pointlist[(3*i) + 1];
            pt.z = out.pointlist[(3*i)+2];
            pt.w = 1;

            Ogre::Vector4 pnt = cameraPose.inverse()*pt;

            float x = ((pnt.x - cameraPosition.x)*cameraIntrinsics.focalLength.x)/pnt.z + cameraPosition.x;
            float y = ((pnt.y - cameraPosition.y)*cameraIntrinsics.focalLength.y)/pnt.z + cameraPosition.y;

            projectedFeaturePoints.push_back(Ogre::Vector2(x,y));

        }
```

One sample values

```
Camera Position ( 0, 1400,0)

(Ogre::Vector4) pt = (x = 255.985977, y = -896.562255, z = 175.277557, w = 1)

(Ogre::Vector4) pnt = (x = 314.670929, y = -963.910278, z = -2083.82031, w = 1)

ProjectedPoint = (Ogre::Vector2) [0] = (x = -0.25423786, y = 1401.90991)
```

Comment: so...., what is the question?

Comment: @Ælex The projected points are not normalized into (-1.1) I get 2D points in the range of 1000 for the y axis

Comment: Your code is badly formatted so I could be wrong, but I see you min-max between 0 and 1. Also I have no clue what the range of your other values are. What have you tried?

Comment: @Ælex Added sample point of the data

Comment: Why do you expect your values to be within the range [-1,1] if you don't normalise them? The only normalisation I see is for `float x` and `float y`, and you are using min-max, possibly incorrectly. See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range